# "Value error: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data "message while extracting numbers from a string from a .txt file using python

Tags: python, arrays, string, parsing

I have a program that grabs numbers from a `.txt` file and puts it into an `array`. The problem is that the numbers are **not isolated** or **ordered**. The `.txt` file looks like this:

```
G40 Z=10
A=30 X10 Y50
A=30 X40 Y15
A=50 X39 Y14
G40 Z=11
A=30 X10 Y50
A=30 X40 Y15
A=50 X39 Y14
```

The output should be a new `.txt` file that has the following array format

```
X Y Z
10 50 10
40 15 10
39 14 10
10 50 11
40 15 11
39 14 11
```

This is what I have done so far, although I'm not sure how to write my output to a new file...

```
inputfile = open('circletest1.gcode' , 'r')
def find_between( s, first, last ):
      try:
          start = s.index( first ) + len( first )
          end = s.index( last, start )
          return s[start:end]
      except ValueError:
          return ""
for i in range(203): inputfile.next() # skip first 203 lines
while True:
    my_text = inputfile.readline()
    z = find_between(my_text, "Z =", " ")
    x = find_between(my_text, "X", " ")
    y = find_between(my_text, "Y", " ")
    print(x ," ", y, " ", z)
    if not my_text:break

inputfile.close()
```

For a while I was receiving indentation errors, but I believe that I have fixed that problem. Now the error message that I am getting is "Value error: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data".

I am not sure where to go from here, nor am I sure how to import my results into another separate new txt file.

Also, in my code, is there a way to preserve the z value outside of the loop until a new z value is assigned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to combine the `Z` value from the lines that start with `G` with the `X` and `Y` values from the following lines (until the next `G` line).

If so, I'd use a single loop, printing only on the lines that start with `A` and just saving the new `Z` value on the lines that start with `G`. I'd do the line parsing with regex, but you could use simple string manipulation if you wanted to (I'd `split` and then skip the first letter or letters of the relevant items).

```
import itertools
import re

z = None

with open('circletest1.gcode') as input_file:
    for line in itertools.islice(203, None):  # islice to skip the first 203 lines
        if line.startswith("G"):
            z = re.search(r"Z=(\d+)", line).group(1)
        elif line.startswith("A"):
            x, y = re.search(r"X(\d+) Y(\d+)", line).groups()
            print(x, y, z)
```

Comment: Thank you! I figured out a solution just as this was posted! Now I'm just trying to figure out how to export the results to a file.